# Is Math.SE for US users only?

Tags: support

I have a cousin in the UK and was wondering if he is able to access this site. I tried to search stackexchange UK, but didn't find a UK site. Is SE, specifically Math.SE, for US users only or is it one site for all countries?

Comment: We in the UK can access this site just as we can access more or less any other site hosted in the US. Why are you looking for a UK site? Amazon UK, for example, exists not because we can't access Amazon US, but because there'll be different products in UK warehouses (and the shipping fee will be lower), because the DVDs they sell have a different regional encoding, and so on.

Comment: I can't help but ask, but did your cousin even try going to the site? I mean, all he would have to do is simply go to math.stackexchange.com to see that he is indeed able to access the site from the UK...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's a proof that UK users are welcome: **http://maths.stackexchange.com** directs here.

Comment: Ooh, I didn't know about that. That's very amusing.

Comment: Shame on you for using proof in such a non-mathematical context on a mathematics related website. ;-)

Comment: @mixedmath: If you dig through the early days of meta.MSE you'll find a request for this redirect for the British speaking parts of the world, G'vnor.

Comment: Though on the level of short links, only http://s.tk/math works.

Comment: This is so hilarious, I laughed so hard towards the monitor for minutes.

Comment: It's a lot better than the proposed *maths.exchange...*

Answer (score 10):

The site is for everyone, everywhere, granted they are being friendly, and keep their posts within the topic of the site (mathematics).

Answer (score 10):

Well, there is a short entrance quiz for UK users:

(1) What is the name of the new royal baby?

(2) What country is Andy Murray from? I mean, really?

(3) What happened recently in a McDonald's near Manchester?

(4) How does that relate to Albuquerque, New Mexico?

Comment: If it's a quiz for Britons, I'd expect something more in the spirit of Monty Python and the Holy Grail...

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I'll send you the answers...

Comment: LOL! I get it I get it! :D

Comment: (1) Prince George Alexander Louis of Cambridge! Weeeee!

Comment: Is (3) related to a horse?

Comment: Yes (3) is about a horse